# Error Apple Mach-O linker Warning on Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I recently updated my app after moving to IOS 7, However now when i run the app its failing to build with the following errors:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/ovalerio/Desktop/GasIt2/../../../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/ovalerio/Desktop/GasIt2/../../../../../../Desktop'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ovalerio/Desktop/GasIt2/GasIt/Facebook/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/ovalerio/Desktop/GasIt2/GasIt/Facebook/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequestConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBDialogs", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLoginView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have double checked the setup including frameworks and resources it all seems correctly setup, anybody know what the issue is? Any help will truly be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the update with 64 bit support. You may need to download a new version of the facebook sdk with arm64 support or change your target to run in 32 bit mode on the 64 bit devices. (only arm7 support)

To remove the support for 64 bit, go to Build Settings and set valid architectures to armv7 and armv7s

Update: Note that as of 1 Febuary 2015, it is now a requirement that all apps submitted to the iOS App store require 64 bit support. This means that you need to update all external libraries to versions which support 64 bit. If they don't have support you may need to delay or remove the feature from the app if you are planning to release it.

If you are planning to deploy your apps ad-hoc, not having 64 bit support may not be an issue, but just be wary that if it wont work on a newer phone that it may be due to the non-64 bit compliance.